# Which object of object types can be passed to Activities inside a Bundle

Tags: android, android-activity, arguments, android-fragmentactivity

I recently taken a online challenge

1) Following questions was asked, i was able to google but could not understand it fully.
2) Does this related to Fragements args as well?

Which object of object types can be passed to Activities inside a Bundle
1.Clonable
2. Serializable
3.Comparable
3.Parselable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the first look `Comparable` and `Clonable` makes no sense to pass to a bundle. Just verified it

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putParcelable(key, value);
    savedInstanceState.putSerializable(key, value);
}
```

So as you can see from list of available methods you can pass `Serializable` and `Parselable` objects.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 3. `Parcelable`, and yes, that works with Fragments' `args` too, as that is of type `Bundle`.

Comment: Right, thanks, was wondering what felt wrong about how that word sounded in my head^^